# JavaScript function is not defined in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, function

This is my script containing the function which is not defined as per error stated.

```
 @section('script')
    <script src="{{ asset('datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('datatable/datatables.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function NewCategory(id = 0, type = "add") 
    {
        if (type == "add") {
            var url = "{{url('admin/categories/create')}}";
        } else {
            var url = "{{url('/admin/categories')}}" + "/" + id + "/edit";
        }  
        $("#myModalContenct").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: "; 
                ErrorAlert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
            } else { 
                $('#CategoryForm').submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    SaveCategory();
                });
                $("#modal").modal("show");
            } 
        });
    }
```

here I called the function

```
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="NewCategory()">
        <i class="fas fa-plus-circle mr-2"></i>
        Add New Category
    </button>
```

I am getting this error

> categories:150 Uncaught ReferenceError: NewCategory is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (categories:150)

Comment: please put here route file code

Comment: Can you show us the whole blade file?

Comment: the whole blade code cannot be added...

Comment: on chrome if you CTRL+ U did you see javascript?

Comment: no. not any javascript code there...

Answer (score 1):

on app.blade make

```
@yield('script2')
```

and use

```
@section('script2')
<script>
//CODE
</script>
@endsection
```

I think you use `@section('script')` twice

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution... by removing @section('script') from the beginning of javascript and @stop from the end of javascript, It worked....